# I had a Sql test, and I want to know if this query is correct (advanced question for experts)

Tags: sql

Query to get the customer_id from customers that have bought products from different categories

```
Select customer_id 
from customer 
  join Purchase_order po on c.customer_id=po.customer_id 
  join order_product op on po.order_id = op.order_id 
  join product p on op.product_id=p.product_id 
  join product_category pc on p.product_category_id = pc.product_category_id 
group by pc.product_category_id
having count(p.product_id)>0
```

[My data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wyzw.jpg)

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm not sure if this query is correct

Comment: Thank you for editing it's more clear now